# CMake FindBoost module and Boost C++ libraries built with BOOST_LIB_BUILDID

Tags: c++, boost, build, cmake

Is it possible to specify the `BOOST_LIB_BUILDID` for an already built Boost C++ library with the CMake [FindBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/FindBoost.html) module?

I am supposed to use a Boost library that is built for x86 and x64 in the same directory, whereas the x64 version has been built with the following `b2` arguments:

```
-layout=versioned --buildid=x64
```

I couldn't find anything related to this in the official CMake documentation.

Comment: You can try to abuse the `Boost_COMPILER` supported by FindBoost.

Comment: No, that does not work. Example: `boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_59-x64`, where `-vc120` is `Boost_COMPILER` and `x64` is `BOOST_LIB_BUILDID`. It seems that it is currently not possible with the `FindBoost` CMake module...